# Draw 3 small squares like a legend in fluidRow() in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny, legend

I am plotting a stacked bar chart using `plot_ly()` and I need to display the legends as a default below the plot in a fluidRow().

I am aware that we can plot legends using `layout` in plotly. But I need to display legends in a separate row with 3 small boxes.

Can anyone provide a solution for creating 3 small boxes in a fluidRow?

[image]

PS: I need to display these in one `fluidRow()`

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please provide a MRE of what you've tried so far, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a very simple function `colorBox` for you. `color` is the legend color, `text` is legend text.

```r
library(shiny)

colorBox <- function(color, text=""){
    div(
        tags$span(text, style = "padding-left: 30px;"),
        div(
            style = paste0("background-color:", 
                           color, "; ",
                           "display: inline-block;
                        position: absolute;
                        height:13px;
                        width: 13px;
                        left: 5px;
                        top: 3px;")),
        style = "position: relative;"
    )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    h1("Legend"),
    fluidRow(
        colorBox("red", "red"),
        colorBox("yellow", "yellow"),
        colorBox("green", "green"),
    ),
    fluidRow(
        style = "width: 300px;",
        column(4, colorBox("red", "red")),
        column(4, colorBox("yellow", "yellow")),
        column(4, colorBox("green", "green")),
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Two layouts:

- First one is vertical;
- Second one is horizontal on a wide screen and vertical on narrow: when you shrink your window width to a narrow view, the legend will become vertical. Try play with your browser width and you will see the difference.